# react native android release crash on startup

Tags: java, android, react-native, kotlin

react native android debug works fine, but when i try to build the apk with
`npx react-native run-android --mode release`
it correctly builds but crashes on startup. I've attached a screenshot of the logcat below. It has something to do with redux because it says it cant access property store. Its code in one of the packages because I am not accessing .store anywhere in my code. But this still doesn't explain why it works in debug but not in release

[logcat fatal exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eiTG.png)

I have tried rebuilding the project several times and it hasn't worked.